# Add a class to parent element

Tags: jquery, html

below is my code and i want to add "active class" to the li element of active link. means i want to add active class to the li tag of which is currently active link.this is i have done , but not working. thank you in advance.

```
$('#rightnav').ready(function() {
    var page = window.location.href.split("/")[5]; 
    if (page == "") { page = "dashboard.php"; }
    $(this).find("ul#rightnav>li a[href$="+page+"]").addClass("active"); 
});




<ul class="nav navbar-nav side-nav" id="rightnav">
            <li><a href="dashboard.php"><i class="fa fa-dashboard"></i> Dashboard</a></li>
            <li><a href="products_list.php"><i class="fa fa-bar-chart-o"></i> Products</a></li>
            <li><a href="charts.html"><i class="fa fa-bar-chart-o"></i> Charts</a></li>
            <li><a href="tables.html"><i class="fa fa-table"></i> Tables</a></li>
            <li><a href="forms.html"><i class="fa fa-edit"></i> Forms</a></li>
            <li><a href="typography.html"><i class="fa fa-font"></i> Typography</a></li>
            <li><a href="bootstrap-elements.html"><i class="fa fa-desktop"></i> Bootstrap Elements</a></li>
            <li><a href="bootstrap-grid.html"><i class="fa fa-wrench"></i> Bootstrap Grid</a></li>
            <li><a href="blank-page.html"><i class="fa fa-file"></i> Blank Page</a></li>
            <li class="dropdown">
              <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"><i class="fa fa-caret-square-o-down"></i> Dropdown <b class="caret"></b></a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a href="#">Dropdown Item</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Another Item</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Third Item</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Last Item</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var page = window.location.href.split("/")[5];
    if (page == "") {
        page = "dashboard.php";
    }

    $('#rightnav > li').has('a[href$="' + page + '"]').addClass("active");
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/7dY94/)

Answer (score 0):

`$(this).find("ul#rightnav>li a[href$="+page+"]").parent().addClass("active");`

What this does is it gets all the elements that match the query string's `parent`s and does `.addClass("active")`.